# Is there a multiplication analogue to Integer::sum?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, higher-order-functions, method-reference

Since Java 8, the `Integer` class has a static `sum` method that adds two integers:

```
public static int sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

I can pass this method to higher-order functions via `Integer::sum` which I find more readable than `(a, b) -> a + b`.

Is there a similar static method for multiplication, so I don't have to write `(a, b) -> a * b`? I couldn't find one in the `Integer` class.

Answer (score 6):

[`Math::multiplyExact`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#multiplyExact-int-int-)

> `static int multiplyExact(int x, int y)`
>
> Returns the product of the arguments, throwing an exception if the result overflows an int.

Comment: Except that this isn't the same as `(a, b) -> a * b` because of its behavior on overflow.

Comment: True. Question wasn't really clear how overflow should be handled, though

Comment: I can't be confident that `Math::multiplyExact` will not suffice for the OP in practice, but it seems reasonable to suppose that he wants a method that has the same semantics in every respect as the lambda he seeks to replace.  Replacing a lambda that will never throw with a method reference that may throw seems a bit dangerous to me.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Personally, I'd prefer an exception over a (probably) undetected overflow. However, it's worth mentioning.

Answer (score 5):

You can make it yourself:

```
public static int mult(int a, int b) {
    return a * b;
}
```

This might seem obvious in retrospect but outside of that I don't believe there's actually a jdk-included method which multiplies for you, *except* for `Math#multiplyExact` (`Math::multiplyExact`), though this might be more than you need.